# ng-grid delete a row by clicking a button outside the grid

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I have an ng-grid which has the Edit and Delete buttons at the bottom of the grid. Both buttons are disabled when no rows are selected.

I want to know what the correct way to delete a row for ng-Grid, when a row is selected.

I could not find any examples from their [website](http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/) or their [wiki](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/wiki.)

Comment: Delete selected items from the grid's source data.

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: How can I downvote both your comments?

Answer (score 1):

I did a quick comparison of the original and the selected... something like this:

```
angular.forEach($scope.gridOptions.selectedItems, function(index) {

    var deleteIndex = $scope.originalResource.indexOf(index);

    if (deleteIndex > -1){
        $scope.originalResource.splice(deleteIndex,1);
    }
});
```

And then to unselect the rows I did this: `$scope.selections.splice(0)`

Answer (score 0):

```
use this it works for both multiple rows or single row selection
 $scope.mySelections = [];
             $scope.gridOptions = {
                 data :'data',
                 selectedItems : $scope.mySelections,
                 showSelectionCheckbox : true
             } 


$scope.delItem = function() {

     for (var i = 0; i < $scope.mySelections.length; i++) {
         var index = $scope.data.indexOf($scope.mySelections[i]);
         if (index != -1) {
             $scope.data.splice(index, 1);
         }
     }
 }
```